# Is it good style to return a reference in this case?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I just stumbled over Evan Teran's answer on [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/), in which he takes a vector by reference, modifies it and returns a reference of it.

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
  std::stringstream ss(s);
  std::string item;
  while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
    elems.push_back(item);
  }
  return elems;
}
```

Is this good style? I see that the advantage is to directly use the result, like in

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
unsigned int uiSize = split("ssad asda", ' ', vec).size();
```

instead of

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
split("ssad asda", ' ', vec);
unsigned int uiSize = .size()
```

Are there any disadvantages? As far as I know, the main reason against returning references is that people might return a reference of a local variable which is destructed after the return. This does not apply here, as the object is not local but given to the method as a parameter.

Comment: I see no problem for this use case for returning reference. it's like `operator<<`

Comment: This is a reasonable thing to do, for chaining commands. For instance, this approach is used for `operator<<` for printing. Still useful for function calls rather than operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
  std::stringstream ss(s);
  std::string item;
  while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
    elems.push_back(item);
  }
  return elems;
}
```

is misleadingly named: it's more of an `append_lines` than `split` function.

But given that, it makes sense to return a reference to the vector, yes. Returning by value could not in general benefit from move semantics, and so would incur some needless overhead. And `void` result could make the calling code pretty clumsy & awkward.